# Sveltekit static adapter environment variables are not working from docker multi stage build

Tags: docker, svelte, sveltekit

I have created a single page app using Sveltekit static-adapter. and with docker-compose and nginx i am able to render the app properly. But i am not able to pass the environment variables from Docker compose to single page app.

Docker file

```
FROM node:16-alpine as dev

WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
RUN [ "npm", "run", "build" ]


FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=dev /src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    container_name: portal
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - '4001:80'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your provided code it looks like you want to pass to your application whether it runs in development or production mode. For exactly this use case Svelte(kit) come with something handy described [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-env)

If in general you want to pass a environment variable, e.g. an API client key, you can make use of environment variable accessor functions described aswell in the [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private).

Svelte comes with a lot of batteries included, so before developing those things on your own check out if Svelte has something in their documentation.